# Where can I find Political Party Affiliation Data?

Tags: geospatial, usa, politics

I would like to make a heat map based on political party membership density in (e.g., California 60% democrat, Kentucky 70% Republican, etc.), preferably at the county level.

Does anyone know of a source for this geography crossed with politics data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MIT Election Data and Science Lab](https://electionlab.mit.edu/data)

They state that "Our lab is a clearinghouse for data sets that can fuel studies on elections and how they're conducted. Find election data and research tools produced by us and others."

Best place to find an election data

---

[Voter Registration - By County and Party](https://dos.myflorida.com/elections/data-statistics/voter-registration-statistics/voter-registration-reportsxlsx/voter-registration-by-county-and-party/)

---

[United States Census Bureau](https://www.census.gov/topics/public-sector/voting/data/datasets.html)

In addition to the Voting and Registration estimates made available on this website, data users can obtain Public Use Microdata Files for elections that the U.S. Census Bureau has data for via [DataFerrett](http://dataferrett.census.gov/), the Bureau's online data access application. The November CPS data files, and entire datasets, are accessible for free through the DataFerrett tool dating back to 1994. The [CPS FTP site](http://thedataweb.rm.census.gov/ftp/cps_ftp.html#cpssupps) is another location for obtaining voting and registration data.

Data users can also obtain CPS Voting and Registration data files from non-governmental websites. The [National Bureau of Economic Research](https://www.nber.org/) website contains voting supplement datasets starting in 1994. The [IPUMS-CPS](https://cps.ipums.org/cps/index.shtml) website maintained by the University of Minnesota includes voting supplement datasets starting in 1976.”

---

[NCSL](https://www.ncsl.org/research/elections-and-campaigns/access-to-and-use-of-voter-registration-lists.aspx)

---

Comment: I keep finding data for voter registration but not broken out by how many voted for different parties, just how many voted. Any suggestions?